# Can an autoregressive process of order $k$ be expressed as a $k$-step Markov chain?

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, time-series, transition-matrix, vector-auto-regression

I am curious if an autoregressive process of order $k:$ $X_{t}= c+ \sum_{i=1}^{k}\phi_i X_{t-i} + \epsilon_i$ can be expressed as
a $k$-step Markov chain with transition probability 
$$ P_{ij}^{k} = Pr(X_{n+k}=j|X_n = i).$$
How this vectorization would look like?

Comment: An $\mathsf{AR}(1)$ model is indeed a Markov chain: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/23789/is-ar1-a-markov-process

Comment: 1. There is no reason to expect that $(X_{nk})_n$ would be a Markov chain if $(X_n)_n$ is AR$(k)$. 2. For every AR$(k)$ process $(X_n)_n$, $$Y_n=(X_n,X_{n-1},\ldots,X_{n-k+1})$$  indeed defines a Markov chain.